Could there be states of matter that could avoid "matter decay"?
Regular structures of matter may decay over extremely long periods of time (especially if proton decay occurs, which is not proven but it remains a possibility)
Even if that happens, are there any states or configurations of matter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter) that would avoid decay and persist? Perhaps some kind of exotic condensate? Or maybe something more normal?
Or maybe could there be bound states made from other standard model particles that we know for sure that can exist (i.e. they are not speculative) that could form structures?

On extremely long time scales, even black holes decay through Hawking radiation. I have never heard it mentioned, but wouldn't it also make other objects decay too?

one angle to investigate is: as nuclear structure can stabilize neutrons against beta decay (or destabilize protons against it)....is there a nucleus bound enough that the GUT proton decay is blocked? (Ofc, then you'd have to worry but neutrons GUT decaying, too)....idk.

Related (I assume): this answer and vengaq's comment on it.

@JEB do you know about any such case?

@vengaq no, not following GUTs since $SU(5)$ flopped, but looking at $p\rightarrow \pi^0 e^+\nu_e$, that has enough energy to overcome any nuclear binding, so cancel the thought.

@benrg I noticed that I didn't fully understand why would quantum tunneling be a problem with the process proposed in that paper. Is it because quantum tunneling would disintegrate all structures? Couldn't the composite particles of these structures re-arrange eventually in that case?

@vengaq The processes you are suggesting are most likely not charge and lepton number conserving. The only thing that would remain after all of this are photons and gravitons and even the electromagnetic field may ultimately not be stable. So that's heat death by graviton emission. What a sad end for the universe.

@FlatterMann what processes are you referring to?

@vengaq The processes you are suggesting. They can certainly not preserve lepton number. Electric charge might be the only symmetry left, but even that is probably on the chopping block in such a scenario, otherwise the single electron in ever expanding spacetime would be safe.

I'm having some trouble understanding you because in this question I'm not proposing any particular process, so I don't know what are you referring to. Are you referring to proton decay? @FlatterMann

Baryon decay can be avoided if you build something out of stable non-baryonic matter. Given our currently known particles that leaves electrons/positrons, and neutrinos.
Stable electron clouds are tricky to do, since they need a gravitational potential that balances their electromagnetic repulsion. Since electromagnetism is much stronger than gravity, this is not doable with electrons. Coulomb repulsion dominates gravitational attraction for any pair of electrons.
However, neutrino stars have been suggested in atrophysics as possible compact objects (back when neutrinos were thought to be heavy) or explaining part of dark matter potentials (now when neutrinos are seen as light). Basically, being fermions cold neutrinos could form spherical condensates kept together by gravity that could be stable. They are not very likely to form according to current theory and observation but are certainly allowed by known physics.
The limit to neutrino star survival is likely set by quantum gravity decay: ocasionally small pieces tunnel into a black hole state that decays into photons that escape. Over very long timescales (I got a number around $10^{555}$ years, but my math is shaky) they would evaporate. Assuming this scenario actually happens.

thank you! A couple of questions on this: 1. As far as I know there could also be "bags" or "clouds" of neutrinos around gravitational potentials (that perhaps are more likely than compact neutrino stars). As neutrinos would be weakly bounded, could these have high amounts of angular momentum? Or they would be static and unmoving so that neutrino particles don't get expelled? 2. Would neutrinos bounded in such rather diffuse structures also suffer tunneling? I mean, could single neutrinos turn into black holes in these "bag" or "cloud" like structures? @AndersSandberg

Neutrino halos likely have little angular momentum, just like other dark matter halo models. They could be static if they have the right profile, although if they have interactions they may gradually suffer dissolution or collapse. The tunneling effect likely applies to anything.

That is a mind boggling number.

@AndersSandberg if neutrinos would tunnel into black holes over extremely extended periods of time, they would be micro black holes. As they would have a high Hawking temperature, would they evaporate back into particles with mass (such as neutrinos)?

@vengaq - Yes, the black hole tunneling is a kind of decay channel, but a more likely decay is to photons. If the hole has mass 2 eV, then it cannot decay to anything heavier.

But if the black hole is 2 eV or around 0.12 eV (which is around the mass if neutrinos en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) couldn't it evaporate into a particle with that mass (a neutrino)? Also considering that according to the Hawking temperarure formula, as the black hole would have a very small mass (the neutrino mass), the temperature would be very high, so wouldn't that mean that it would instantly evaporate into a massive particle with that mass (i.e. a neutrino)? @AndersSandberg

@vengaq - Black holes cannot produce more energy than went into them. So if a 0.2 eV neutrino imploded, the hole will no matter what its temperature produce either photons, other mass-less particles, or a single neutrino.

@AndersSandberg and would there be any way or any situations in which that the micro black hole coming from that neutrino would be guaranteed to evaporate into a single neutrino again?

@vengaq - This feels like a separate question worth posing: how does very small quantum black holes decay when their mass is lower than most particles, yet their Hawking temperature is vast?

Would electrons also be susceptible to that fate? Could they also tunnel into micro black holes? @AndersSandberg
